# Java Runtime OR Processbuilder OR Other

Tags: java, runtime, processbuilder

I'd like to know what the best alternative is for running command line executables from Java.  The Target platforms for the commands are Windows 7(+) and Unix/Linux.

I have a class that currently uses Runtime.exec() along with the enhancements from the JavaWorld StreamGobbler article.  It works about 90% of the time on both Windows and Unix.  The other 10% of the time I need to extend the class and then fiddle with putting cmd.exe of /bin/sh in front of the command.  I've also had to fiddle sometimes between using a single String that has command and arguments to splitting the command and args into a String[] array.

My latest is a new error/exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments."  My current Runtime.exec() class works fine in Eclipse running as a Java application, but once I build it and run from an actually command prompt, it fails with the above exception.

So now I'm reading that we should be using ProcessBuilder to do command line executables to the OS platform.

My question is, what is the best alternative?  Runtime.exec(), ProcessBuilder, or some other option?  Is there one option that will service both Windows and Unix/Linux?  If not, which one works best with Windows?  Which one works best with Unix/Linux?

tia, adym

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` was created to solve difficulties with `Runtime`. Use `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to give Bohemian credit, but I used ProcessBuilder...Solution is at :

[Java - ProcessBuilder command arguments with spaces and double-quotes fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314645/java-processbuilder-command-arguments-with-spaces-and-double-quotes-fails)