# Execute Command work in cmd and not work in java code

Tags: java, cloud

i have problem with this code 
i use the CLC (cloud fondry)to deplyer the application in the cloud 
my code is

```
public class cmd1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] command =
        {
            "cmd",
        };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        stdin.println("dir c:\\ /A /Q");  //ca march bien 


        stdin.println("cf login");        //ca march    

        stdin.println("hakimguettaoui@gmail.com");   //ici si j'ai fait un login il me demander Email et mot de pass mais il me 
                                                     // donnée un pb 
        stdin.println("");


        // write any other commands you want here
        stdin.close();
        int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);

}
```

}

```
class SyncPipe implements Runnable {


public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
 istrm_ = istrm;
 ostrm_ = ostrm;}
 public void run() {
 try
 {
     final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
     {
         ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
 }catch (Exception e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } } private final OutputStream ostrm_; private final InputStream istrm_;
```

}

all of command is work but 
if i use cf login is work but the authentification 
is not work lock the err 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4PY1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it correctly, separate Threads for STDOUT and STDERR.  After using Runtime for years, I switched to ProcessBuilder...Maybe switch to ProcessBuilder.  See the following posts on this :

[Java Runtime OR Processbuilder OR Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302140/java-runtime-or-processbuilder-or-other)

[Java - ProcessBuilder command arguments with spaces and double-quotes fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314645/java-processbuilder-command-arguments-with-spaces-and-double-quotes-fails)